# Blank Pages using Report lab canvas

Tags: python, reportlab

My use case is to merge all the PDF files available in the folder followed by adding "xxxx" and "page number 1 of 11" as footer to all pages.

I have been using report lab for my use case, however PDF files produced through Adobe Distiller is rendering as blank pages with no content from the original PDF and with just "XXXX" and page 2 of 11"

```
[input_file = file_name+'.pdf'
output_file = file_name+'.pdf'

# Get pages
reader = PdfReader(input_file)
pages = \[pagexobj(p) for p in reader.pages\]


# Compose new pdf
canvas = Canvas(output_file)        
for page_num, page in enumerate(pages, start=1):

    # Add page
    canvas.setPageSize((page.BBox\[2\], page.BBox\[3\]))
    #canvas.setPageSize(14*inch, 8.5*inch)
    #scanvas.setPageSize(self, size)
    #canvas.setPageSize(pair)
    canvas.doForm(makerl(canvas, page))

    # Draw footer
    footer_text1 = "xxxx"
    footer_text = "Page %s of %s" % (page_num, len(pages))
    x = 128
    y = 10
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(0, 0, 0)
    #canvas.setLineWidth(0.5)
    #canvas.line(66, 78, page.BBox\[2\] - 66, 78)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 10)
    canvas.drawString(page.BBox\[2\]-x, 20, footer_text)
    canvas.drawString(35, 20, footer_text1)
        #canvas.drawString(100, 20, footer_text)
    canvas.restoreState()

    canvas.showPage()

canvas.save()][1]
```